# Microsoft Graph: Get user's actual outlook email address

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to use Microsoft Graph API to retreive authenticated user's outlook email.

The recommended approach is to send a request to `/me` and pull either the email or user principal name.

The problem I'm facing is that whenever there's a customer who created a Microsoft account via gmail, their principal name and email would reference their gmail account. i.e **bobby@gmail.com**.

The customers would still have their outlook account and address would be automatically generated i.e **outlook_A0C234612345699BE@outlook.com.** That address is used whenever they send an email out from outlook.

I've went through their documentation and looked on SO but cannot see anybody solving that.

Is there any way for me to pull their actual outlook address?

Comment: Did you look at the proxyaddresses attribute, in o365 the reply address should be prefixed with SMTP (in capitals).